# Configuring Serilog.Extensions.Logging.File

Tags: c#, logging, asp.net-core, serilog

Following the instructions at [Nicholas Blumhardt's page](https://nblumhardt.com/2016/10/aspnet-core-file-logger/) and later the [Serilog github page](https://github.com/serilog/serilog-extensions-logging-file), I am having issues getting Serilog to work. Specfically

> Error    CS1061  'ILoggerFactory' does not contain a definition for 'AddFile' and no extension method 'AddFile' accepting a first argument of type 'ILoggerFactory' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

I have downloaded the latest package from from NuGet.  My .proj has the following entry `<PackageReference Include="Serilog.Extensions.Logging" Version="2.0.2" />`

I've restarted Visual Studio after installing.

**Startup.cs** (1st Tute)

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
{
    loggerFactory.AddFile("Logs/app-{Date}.txt");
```

**Program.cs** (2nd Tute)

```
public static IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
    WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
        .ConfigureLogging((hostingContext, builder) =>
        {
            builder.AddFile("Logs/myapp-{Date}.txt");
        })
        .UseStartup<Startup>();
```

What makes this worse is I did this for a project over a year ago and comparing to that I can't see what I'm doing wrong :(

Answer (score 11, accepted):

For one way, follow steps below:

1. Install package `Serilog.Extensions.Logging.File` with `1.1.0`

   ```
   <PackageReference Include="Serilog.Extensions.Logging.File" Version="1.1.0" />
   ```
2. Register `AddFile` in `Startup.cs`

   ```
       public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env,        
    ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
   {
       loggerFactory.AddFile("Logs/app-{Date}.txt");
   ```

Comment: The difference between `Serilog.Extensions.Logging` and `Serilog.Extensions.Logging.File` >_<

Comment: Remember to create the output directory yourself if it does not exist, else this won't work and won't give any error.